# swap function not working in golang

Tags: go

Actually i just start to learn golang . In the beginning i think that `=` and `:=` are same . But then  i understand that there is some difference between this two .

I learned swap function in golnag

```
import "fmt"

func swap(x, y string) (string, string) {
    return y, x
}

func main() {
    a, b := swap("hello", "world")
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

But when i rewrite this function using `var` this is not working

```
package main

import "fmt"

func swap(x, y string) (string, string) {
    return y, x
}

func main() {
   var a, b string
    a ="hello"
    b="world"
     swap(a, b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

what is the error in this program ?

Comment: You are not utilizing the `swap()` return values in the second case, so the variables stay as they are.

Comment: You aren’t assigning the result back to a,b

Comment: thank you . but i try a, b := swap(a, b) this also error . no new variables on left side of :=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that in second case values returned from `swap` are ignored. SO nothing is changed.

Try:  https://play.golang.org/p/uADEf5X15g

```
package main

import "fmt"

func swap(x, y string) (string, string) {
    return y, x
}

func main() {
    var a, b string
    a = "hello"
    b = "world"
    a, b = swap(a, b)  ////   <----
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375975/how-to-redirect-all-mobile-folder-files-to-main-folder-file-using-htacess

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use pointers:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func swap(x, y *string) {
    *x, *y = *y, *x
}

func main() {
    var a, b string
    a ="hello"
    b="world"
    swap(&a, &b)
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-vxUMlaVmN

Comment: The real solution for swap is this one. Other method does not swap value, instead, they return the input value in inverse order.

Answer (score 3):

To respond your initial question, you should assign the values returned by swap to a and b like so

```
a, b = swap(b, a)
```

Notice that this is simple assignment , without the `:` attached to the equal

also, instead of a `swap` function, you could just try inplace reassignment:
`a, b = b, a`

Answer (score 2):

### Variables declaration

- `var a string` - declaration of a variable with null value
- `a := "spam"` - declaration of a variable with a concrete value
- `func f(a, b string) (string, string) {` - declaration of a function with value parameters. It means you have new variables with passed values as arguments each time you call a function.
- `func f(a, b *string) (*string, *string) {` - declaration of a function with pointer arguments. In it's turn it means you have pointers to passed variables each time you call the function.

Also...

- `a := *string` - declaration of a pointer variable.
- `*a` - value of a pointer variable.
- `&a` - pointer of a value

### In-place swap

To swap in-place (without returning and reassigning) you should swap values between pointers.

```
func swap(a, b *string) {
    *a, *b = *b, *a
}
```

p.s.

Take into account that strings is read-only slices of bytes. And slices are reference type it means that an array behind the sub-slices of a common array or slice is the same. It doesn't related to the question but should be considered in such cases.

Comment: thank you .If you can explain me    Big = 1 << 100 in  https://tour.golang.org/basics/16 and cmplx.Sqrt(-5 + 12i) in https://tour.golang.org/basics/11 then it is very helpful

Comment: Ask it as questions it will be easier to maintain and give complete answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111223/what-is-the-main-purpose-for-operator-in-golang

Comment: i think i will get negative vote if i post this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111223/what-is-the-main-purpose-for-operator-in-golang / . And i get .

Comment: Negative votes it is ok. To avoid it you should formulate your question precisely and be sure you have done enough research and the answer is not a first line in google for "complex number type".